# Ocultar diretórios na url

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber se existe algum meio no PHP de ocultar o caminho dos diretórios na **url** do navegador.

Por exemplo, é assim que aparece: localhost/teste/view/home.php

Existe alguma possibilidade de mostrar somente o **.php** na url, sem mostrar todo caminho ?

Comment: Existem várias formas de ser feito, você utiliza algum framework, como Laravel ou Zend?

Comment: Não, uso php "puro".

Comment: Você está tentando usar o padrão MVC?

Comment: Voce pode criar N regras no seu arquivo .htaccess, no exemplo você cita algo específico, mas creio que queira algo dinâmico...com alguma pesquisa você encontra várias informações, ou opção seria usar o micro-framework Slim.

Comment: Sim, uso padrão MVC.

Comment: Então, você está fazendo errado. O arquivo home.php poderá ser acessado por essa URL que você informou, no entanto, o correto é que ele seja acessado por meio do seu controller. Sugiro que dê uma olhada nesse vídeo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q8ekGIkU2jE

Comment: Olá Kevin.
Porque você quer mostrar somente o .php? Não vejo sentido nisso. Normalmente o pessoal quer é esconder o .php.
Seria algo como http://localhost/.php?

Comment: Opa, na verdade seria isso: localhost/home.php